# Can anyone tell how to get MAC address of all system in LAN

Tags: java, mac-address

i am doing my 8th Sem project,
one of the module of the project is to find all MAC address of System which are connected in the LAN & store them in a file...

please let me know whether i can do it or not....

i want a JAVA Code to do the this thing, or anyone can give me some hints to do this

all are welcome to comment on this & support me....

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

With pure Java it is impossible. You could execute "[arp](http://linux.die.net/man/8/arp)" thru Runtime.execute() and parse the output.

Answer (score 1):

1. ping/connect all machines in subnet (like nmap -sP )
2. read the system arp table (arp -n)
3. store them in the file

Answer (score 0):

Use Nmap and Nmap4j and you should be good to go.

nmap4j.sourceforge.net is a Java API that wraps Nmap.  Nmap is a port scanner that would be able to give you MAC address and OS information.